# Could not configure Firebase InstanceID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

hi I'm trying to include firebase in my app and followed the documentation, when I'm trying to do google sign in, Could not configure Firebase InstanceID error occurs .please advice how to overcome this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add your project which is created on

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios or fire base console into your Firebase dashboard.

Now you can download **GoogleService-Info.plist** from Firebase and import into your project.

Answer (score 10):

There are two things to check (and hopefully, one will fix it for you):

1. Make sure your **BundleIdentifier** is exactly the same in your Firebase project as it is in your Xcode, i.e. ***com.[yourcompany].[yourappname]***
2. Make sure you got the latest **GoogleService-Info.plist** file. Go to *Firebase Console -> Settings -> Your Application* - there will be a blue button to the right that lets you download new configuration file

That solved it for me.

Comment: thanks! I just had to download the .plist file again and it worked :)

Answer (score 9):

**Bug Details**

As of version `3.13.0`, there appears to be a bug in the `Firebase/Core` SDK.

I added a symbolic breakpoint at `-[FIRInstanceID(FIRApp) configureInstanceIDWithOptions:app:]` and stepped though the assembly.
It appears that `FIRApp.configure()` is ignoring the `IS_GCM_ENABLED` flag in the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` and tries to configure GCM regardless of the flag's state. In my case, because my project does not use GCM, the app would crash because there was no `GCM_SENDER_ID` in the plist.

**Workaround**

Add a dummy value (i.e. `123456789012`) for `GCM_SENDER_ID` within the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. This will allow the application to configure successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I setup Firebase in code using `FIROptions`. In my case, I was missing `gcmSenderID`, fixing it then it works

Answer (score 1):

Firebase DevRel here. This should be an error, unless you enabled gcm, you shouldn't go through instanceid setup. Filed internally.

For now, the workaround is manually changing "IS_GCM_ENABLED" to "NO" in your "GoogleService-Info.plist" file

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as I didn't have my `GoogleService-Info.plist` in my Test folder as well. ( if you are using TDD)

As of the latest Firebase Core 3.16.0 - I seem to need to include it in my main project as well as copying a version into my Test Root.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you shift your google SDK integration from one account to another and don't edit the API keys on application side.
Make sure when you shift from one google account to another, you re-visit all the SDK guides again like FCM, Google Sign-in etc and make sure you are using new API keys (client_id, URI Scheme) in application.