# Getting App crash while using Firebase Phone auth

Tags: ios

The app is crashing at **[FIRApp configure]**;

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.instanceid', 
>        reason: 'Could not configure Firebase InstanceID. GCM_SENDER_ID must 
>        not be nil or empty.

Comment: Did you see these answers? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249513/6835002 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42988135/6835002

Comment: now i am getting this error ,If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.

Comment: Formatted to readable

Comment: can you describe more